# OPENGL ES glRotatef

Tags: java, android, graphics, opengl-es

I just want to be completely clear. I am still new to Open GL and learning mostly though trial & error.

When I use the glRotatef(angle, x, y, z)

anything I draw from that point on will be rotated by the specified amount, on the specified axis?

So how would I undo such a rotation?

```
    glRotatef(45, 0, 0, 1);
    // draw object
    glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

would that work?

to be clear for what I need, when the user drags a finger across the screen it draws a line at a given angle, and I am taking that angle and applying it to a textured square.

How ever I have many object I draw before and after this square that I do not want rotated.

So far i think it is safe to say, that when you apply a transformation/rotation/translation/texture that until you specify other wise it will stay that way?

Comment: glRotatef is deprecated. I wouldn't recommend using it for new code.

Comment: @luiscubal true but it sounds like he is using OpenGL ES 1.1 in which case it would be quite the learning curve to change - certainly far more than just not using glRotatef.. Its a whole other can of worms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenGL transformation FAQ covers this: http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm

You could calculate the inverse of every transform operation and I pretty sure the correct way in that case would be `glRotatef(-45, 0, 0, 1)`. This quickly gets complicate when you start adding scales and translates into the mix. A far simpler solution is to wrap transformations with `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix`

For Example:

```
// save the current matrix state
glPushMatrix() 

// Transform
glTranslate(...)
glRotate(...)

// Issue a draw call
glDrawArrays(...)

// Restore the transformation matrix to when it was saved.
glPopMatrix()
```

After poping the matrix you can go about your buisness like the transformation never happened.
This is also extremely useful for hierarchal transformations as you can have multiple push-pop sequences inside of each other.

Comment: Wow, so simple an explanation, and what i've been looking for for hours just like that. (not many people bother to explain the meaning of all the calls in examples)